# Material UI paper with dynamic height and width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a Material-UI based paper (https://mui.com/components/paper/)
Where there are some content inside of the Paper and they are supposed to be Dynamic.

```
<Paper className="modal" elevation={3}>
...Content
</Paper>

// CSS property
.modal {
  width: 90%;
  height: 95%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I want to have the paper to be scrollable, and the content to adapt to the Paper, currently the dynamic content is flowing out of the Paper.

Is there anyway we could make it dynamic so that the width and height adjust on itself?

Answer (score 0):

Height of the content should be set to auto so that the height can be adjusted based on the content automatically.

```
height: auto;
```